# What is the difference between a "ChromeBox" - and a "Chrome Book"?

Tags: google-chrome-os

I have a Chrome "Box".  What is the difference between a "ChromeBox" - and a "Chrome Book"?

Comment: Box is a desktop type pc, Book is a Notebook (laptop) PC.

Answer (score 2):

A Chromebook is a traditional notebook PC, also known as a laptop. The display screen, keyboard, and touch-pad are all built into the device that folds shut with a hinge.

A Chromebox is square, thick, and compact, and it contains a CPU and an SSD like a Chromebook but has no display screen, keyboard, or touch-pad.  Instead, the user must add these separately as peripherals using the USB and HDMI ports on the sides of the device.

A Chromebase is a very large desktop display monitor that has a has a Chromebox built seamlessly into it and that comes with the keyboard and mouse.

Answer (score 1):

`Chromebook and Chromebox` are notebook and desktop that run Google’s Chrome OS. 
`Notebooks` (known as Chromebooks) and `Desktops`(Chromeboxes), for more comparison [click here](http://www.edtechmagazine.com/k12/article/2014/12/vs-chromebook-or-chromebox)